# Why does "uname -o" return GNU/Linux instead of Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, release-management

I known that the `uname -o` command will display the operating system. But when I run that on Ubuntu 20.04, I get

```
GNU/Linux
```

not `Ubuntu`. Why is it like this?

Comment: Ubuntu is a GNU/Linux distribution, and I don't see your issue as I consider it a valid answer for "operating system" or the `-o` option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ubuntu is a GNU/Linux distribution.

`man uname` tells me the -o options report

> ```
>    -o, --operating-system
>           print the operating system
> ```

To me that is a valid answer, Ubuntu shows instead who packaged up the GNU/Linux operating system you are using.

I'd usually use `lsb_release -a` to view details about what GNU/Linux I'm using, for my system I get

```
guiverc@d960-ubu2:~$    lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu Groovy Gorilla (development branch)
Release:        20.10
Codename:       groovy
```

Comment: FYI:  LSB = *linux standard base*; I don't use it (*thus the no LSB modules found message*), as most of us won't, but that command still provides decent details even if we're not using (IBM's wanted) LSB.